# Features disappear when switching 2D to 3D?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, cesium

I'm working on OL3-Cesium. Right now my main focus is to add parallel lines to a given line string. That's working perfectly fine in 2D view. But as soon as I switch to 3D view, the parallel lines I added disappear. I'm unable to pin point the problem. Or is it a limitation with Cesium ?
I've provided a gif describing the same.

[http://i.imgur.com/kmtkW5D.gif](https://i.imgur.com/kmtkW5D.gif)

As you can see, I'm able to create lines parallel to the original line string. But as soon as I switch to 3D view (Blue flash) , all that remains is single line string. New line strings disappear. 
I'm not able to catch the mistake. I've done almost the same thing earlier as well, that was with polygons. i.e. earlier also I've added features corresponding to the existing features in 2D mode and they stayed in 3D view as well. But this time, it's not working.

Views/ suggestions please ?

**Edit**:
Hi all, I found the solution and have posted it in the answer section.
Can anyone now help me understand the reason why this change of feature type resulted in disappearance of the features in 3D view ?

Answer (score 2):

I found out what the mistake was, a very silly mistake actually.
I was preparing arrays of coordinates for the parallel lines, but at the time of creation of features, I was creating polygons instead of new line strings.
In terms of OL3, it should've been

```
new ol.geom.LineString(coordinate array, 'XYZ');
```

But what I was doing was:

```
new ol.geom.Polygon(coordinate array,'XYZ');
```

I still don't know how this mistake can affect the appearance/ disappearance of line string on map, but ya, for now the problem is solved.